# Accept datetime isoformat in Django form

Tags: python, django, validation, datetime, timezone

There is an API server build on top of Django. Model `Author` has `DateTimeField` which is serialised to iso formatted string, such as `2015-04-10T07:28:45.571039+00:00`.

```
class Author(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField()
```

Client is implemented in Javascript. It builds model with given datetime field, so to update the model, I would like to use field in the same format.

To process request on server side, there is a model form

```
class AuthorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
```

POST/PUT request handler raises exception: "Enter a valid date/time.". Reason for that is allowed [DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS). There is no way to accept timezone information with colon inside.

Given that I don't want to remove timezone support (USE_TZ) and would like to accept data with timezone information, what is the way to implement server side? I currently have two solutions: 1) exclude field at all 2) use `CharField` in form with `dateutil.parser.parse` function inside form clean method.
Do you have any suggestions how to deal with it?

Answer (score 2):

Python (pre 3.7) can't handle an ISO8601 string with +00:00. The colon, specifically, is the problem (see: https://bugs.python.org/issue15873, https://bugs.python.org/msg169952). Django does, however, provide a solution via `django.utils.dateparse.parse_datetime` (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30449246/5043802)

To solve this problem, you can roll out your own DateTimeField that uses `parse_datetime` instead.

https://gist.github.com/elnygren/da7a1b7496a598f95bc8d8277f420b2d

```
    from django import forms
    from django.utils.dateparse import parse_datetime
    from django.utils.encoding import force_str
    from django.forms.widgets import DateTimeInput
    from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _, ngettext_lazy


    class ISODateTimeField(forms.Field):
        """DateTimeField that uses django.utils.dateparse.parse_datetime.

        More precisely, this DateTimeField accepts ISO 8601 datetime strings 
        that specify timezone with +00:00 syntax.

        https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601
        https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11385
        https://bugs.python.org/issue15873
        https://bugs.python.org/msg169952
        """
        widget = DateTimeInput
        default_error_messages = {
            'invalid': _('Enter a valid date/time.'),
        }

        def to_python(self, value):
            value = value.strip()
            try:
                return self.strptime(value, format)
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid'], code='invalid')

        def strptime(self, value, format):
            """ stackoverflow won't let me save just an indent! """
            return parse_datetime(force_str(value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your storage is unlikely to accept timezone aware datetimes, is your django app set up for timezones? from the docs:

> When support for time zones is enabled, Django stores datetime
>   information in UTC in the database, uses time-zone-aware datetime
>   objects internally, and translates them to the end user’s time zone in
>   templates and forms.

also if you're not using postgresql:

> Other backends store datetimes without time zone information. If you
>   switch from USE_TZ = False to USE_TZ = True, you must convert your
>   data from local time to UTC – which isn’t deterministic if your local
>   time has DST.

Bascially it's not completely done for you just be setting USE_TZ in settings.py

Comment: I use Postgres and my settings "USE_TZ = True", so django is set up for timezones (otherwise serialised date in description would not have "+00:00" suffix).

Comment: I think there is no issue with storage because I could reproduce error for correct data rejecting its format via DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS settings.

Answer (score 0):

i use @elnygren code and i have a bug with a form that ISODateTimeField field is not required, it tries to validate all the time, i fix this way:

```
def to_python(self, value):
    if value in self.empty_values:
        return None
    value = value.strip()
    for _format in self.input_formats:
        try:
            return self.strptime(value, _format)
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            continue
    raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages["invalid"], code="invalid")
```